# regex to get linkable text

Tags: regex, pcre

I've been trying for hours now.
I need to get the linkable text meaning, all text from a webpage source that is between `<a href>` and `</a>` except the other tags that are nested between the `<a>` tags.
Example:

```
    <a href="blabla.net">THIS TEXT
<img src="hhh.jpg" />           THIS TEXT TOO
               <span> ALSO THIS TEXT. </span>AND ALSO THIS TEXT</a>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried yet?

Comment: What language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regular expression with a non greedy group:

```
<[aA]\b[^\>]*>([\w\W]*?)<\/[aA]>
```

You can test it on this page by hitting F12 then typing

```
$(document.body).html().match(/<a\b[^\>]*>([\w\W]*?)<\/a>/ig)
```

Comment: That does not match when there are tags inside the link

Comment: @PoulBak Did you test it ? Just do it on this page and you'll see it works

Comment: Not when there's multiple lines. Besides, he doesn't want the img and span tags returned, only the text.

Comment: multiple lines in HTML can be easily removed. For the span tags, I dunno, I obviously didn't  read the question the same way than you. In any case, OP doesn't seem to care about this question, so I won't waste time guessing his need.

Comment: your expression works only if the html code is on the same line, also, I don't want the inner tags returned. I have edited the question to reflect that the html code is on several lines

Comment: I've edited my answer but you **must** precise the language or tool you're using. A regex isn't used alone, it's used in functions and with flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Regular expression, that returns the text between tags in four groups:

```
(?<=>)[^<]+?(?=<)
```

It removes tags from the text.